# Issue creating a countdown timer - minutes/seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a countdown timer in minutes and seconds that that displays on the page - all seems to work fine with the bit of code I have. The only issue is when the alert box pops up I want the clock to stop counting down also.

I thought that including the return keyword under the alert pop up would resolve the issue but the clock keep ticking down.

Below is the code. Any help would be great.

```
  window.onload = function() {

  var hour = 1;
  var sec = 59;

  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hour + " : " + sec;
    sec--;
     if (sec == 0) {
       hour--;
       sec = 59; 
       } 
       if (hour == 1 && sec == 51)
        {
            alert("Stop, you have not completed the task in the alotted time");
            return;
        }             
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Capture the interval id in a variable (`let int = setInterval(...)`) and just after the `alert()`, call `clearInterval(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timeout, not an interval. Intervals trigger until they're stopped. Timeouts happen once.

```
const interval = setInterval( function() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hour + " : " + sec;
  sec--;
  if (sec == 0) {
    hour--;
    sec = 59; 
   }
});

const timeoutPeriod = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

setTimeout(
  function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("Stop, you have not completed the task in the alotted time");
  }, timeoutPeriod
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to save that Interval in a variable and then deactivate the interval with clearInterval. So your code would be like this:

```
 window.onload = function() {

  var hour = 1;
  var sec = 59;

  let counting_interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hour + " : " + sec;
    sec--;
     if (sec == 0) {
       hour--;
       sec = 59; 
       } 
       if (hour == 1 && sec == 51)
        {
            alert("Stop, you have not completed the task in the alotted time");
            clearInterval(counting_interval); // pass the interval as the argument and it will stop to call the interval anymore
            return;
        }             
    }, 1000);

}
```